# A wire came off the light switch - where to put it back safely?

Tags: electrical

I've turned off the fuses in the entire house.

I've opened the light switch hoping that maybe I'll be able to fix one annoying issue.

In the process of opening, one wire slid out and I'm unsure where to put it back.

[image]

[image]

*(maybe you'll know instantly, maybe additional information required)*

## Additional information to help investigate

It is a triple switch:

- light in the kitchen
- light in the bathroom
- extractor in the bathroom to get rid of the hot steam from the shower

At some point, the one of the switches got stuck and a friend of mine did a "temporary" fix:

- light in the kitchen and light on the bathroom connected together
- UNUSED
- extractor

Recently I've noticed that the switch got unstuck so I thought (this morning) that maybe I can connect it the original triple way but:

- they are not clearly described
- in the process of opening one wire slid out
- I do not know how to safely put it back

Some more information:

- the switch that got stuck and then unstuck is the middle
- when I was turning off the fuses one-by-one, the extractor was connected to a different fuse than the lights

## I just want to but put it back to the "temporary" way

Please tell me where to put it back

Comment: The switch on that side. The side with the problem.  Think about the light it controls. Is there more than 1 switch which controls that light?  Also if you look down into the ports there, do you see any with a tightened screw clamping a broken off nub of wire?

Comment: European colours specify blue for neutral, and there should not be any neutral (blue) wire at the switch. This is thus non-standard wiring, you probably need to get help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each gray "Y" on the back handles one circuit. Also, each can act like a "normal" 1-way switch (on/off) or part of a 3-way switch (2 switches controlling the same circuit with the switches at different parts of the room/hallway/etc). For 1-way use you are supposed to use COM and L1 and leave L2 empty. For 3-way use you use L1, L2 and COM on both of two switches. You have 1-way use.

Here's the problem - you say there are 3 circuits (light, light, and fan). However, on the photo we see 4 different wires attached at COM connections.  There are also 3 other wires, 2 on L2(?) connections and 1 loose.

Normally, you would expect to have 1 incoming wire and 1 outgoing wire to each switch. You will have to figure out what each wire is connected to wire this correctly.

The "temporary" fix probably combined some wires from different circuits. This can lead to overheating and a fire, so it's best to sort this out quickly.

Comment: Three-way (North American usage) is generally called **Two-way** where this sort of hardware/voltage/wire color scheme is used. Separated by a common language, etc... A Three-way (there) would be a Four-way (North American usage.) And yes, whoever wired this throughly ignored "One-way use L1" molded into the switch.